# Text fields in geogebra are constantly disappearing

Tags: geogebra

So, I want to make a text field in geogebra showing a sine of an angle. I creat a field in place I want, I input the correct text, click enter, and... nothing. It bloody disappears. It's still in the system, I can see it in the list of objects, hut it's permanently invisible. The little freaking dot next to it is white, and it should be blue. If I click it, it doesn't become blue, unlike every freaking other object. What the f do I do?

Comment: Can you please share whatever code you already have so that we can see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a dynamic text, try typing this (if your angle is called 'α')

> "sine = " + sin(α)

If not, please explain more exactly what you want